# MongoDB Aggregation on multiple nested arrays

Tags: mongodb, nested, pymongo, aggregation

I'm trying to work out how to query a document which has two layers of nested arrays.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7fb679d76f3bbf82ed952e"),
    "org-name" : "Shropshire Community Health NHS Trust",
    "domain" : "shropscommunityhealth.nhs.uk",
    "subdomains" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "www.shropscommunityhealth.nhs.uk",
            "firstSeen" : "2015-10-17 01:10:00",
            "a_rr" : "195.49.146.9",
            "data_retrieved" : ISODate("2019-09-16T17:21:11.468Z"),
            "asn" : 21472,
            "asn_org" : "ServerHouse Ltd",
            "city" : "Portsmouth",
            "country" : "United Kingdom",
            "shodan" : {
                "ports" : [ 
                    {
                        "port" : 443,
                        "cpe" : "cpe:/a:microsoft:internet_information_server:8.5",
                        "product" : "Microsoft IIS httpd"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "port" : 80,
                        "cpe" : "cpe:/o:microsoft:windows",
                        "product" : "Microsoft HTTPAPI httpd"
                    }
                ],
                "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-09-16T17:21:12.659Z")
            }
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "www2.shropscommunityhealth.nhs.uk",
            "firstSeen" : "2017-06-23 16:55:00",
            "a_rr" : "80.175.25.17",
            "data_retrieved" : ISODate("2019-09-16T17:21:12.663Z"),
            "asn" : 8607,
            "asn_org" : "Timico Limited",
            "city" : null,
            "country" : "United Kingdom",
            "shodan" : {
                "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-09-16T17:21:13.664Z")
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to be able to search through the collection and return all of the subdomains where where there is a match on the port number supplied. So far I've tried (in PyMongo)

```
result = db.aggregate([{'$match': {'subdomains.shodan.ports.port': port}},
                            {'$project': {
                                'subdomains': {'$filter': {
                                    'input': '$subdomains.shodan.ports',
                                    'cond': {'$eq': ['$$this.port', port]}
                                }}
                            }}])
```

When I run this I don't get any results back at all. I've played around with my `$filter` but can't seem to get any results out. I'm using a similar aggregation for querying within just the `subdomains` array and it works fine, I'm just struggling with the array within an array and wondering if I need a different approach.

Comment: you need to unwind the first array then impelement $filter and then $group them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try aggregate pipeline below:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$subdomains"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "subdomains.shodan.ports": {
        $elemMatch: {
          port: 443
        },
        $ne: null
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      "org-name": {
        $last: "$org-name"
      },
      "domain": {
        $last: "$domain"
      },
      "subdomains": {
        $push: "$subdomains"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

giving output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5d7fb679d76f3bbf82ed952e"),
    "domain": "shropscommunityhealth.nhs.uk",
    "org-name": "Shropshire Community Health NHS Trust",
    "subdomains": [
      {
        "a_rr": "195.49.146.9",
        "asn": 21472,
        "asn_org": "ServerHouse Ltd",
        "city": "Portsmouth",
        "country": "United Kingdom",
        "data_retrieved": ISODate("2019-09-16T17:21:11.468Z"),
        "firstSeen": "2015-10-17 01:10:00",
        "name": "www.shropscommunityhealth.nhs.uk",
        "shodan": {
          "ports": [
            {
              "cpe": "cpe:/a:microsoft:internet_information_server:8.5",
              "port": 443,
              "product": "Microsoft IIS httpd"
            },
            {
              "cpe": "cpe:/o:microsoft:windows",
              "port": 80,
              "product": "Microsoft HTTPAPI httpd"
            }
          ],
          "timestamp": ISODate("2019-09-16T17:21:12.659Z")
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, the $unwind was the bit I was missing. Actually ended up with the $unwind and then running a $project to tidy up the output to exactly what I need from the query. Thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project:{
            "subdomains":{
                $filter:{
                    "input":"$subdomains",
                    "as":"subdomain",
                    "cond":{
                        $in:[
                            443, 
                            { 
                                $ifNull:[
                                    "$$subdomain.shodan.ports.port",
                                    []
                                ] 
                            } 
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7fb679d76f3bbf82ed952e"),
    "org-name" : "Shropshire Community Health NHS Trust",
    "domain" : "shropscommunityhealth.nhs.uk",
    "subdomains" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "www.shropscommunityhealth.nhs.uk",
            "firstSeen" : "2015-10-17 01:10:00",
            "a_rr" : "195.49.146.9",
            "data_retrieved" : ISODate("2019-09-16T17:21:11.468Z"),
            "asn" : 21472,
            "asn_org" : "ServerHouse Ltd",
            "city" : "Portsmouth",
            "country" : "United Kingdom",
            "shodan" : {
                "ports" : [ 
                    {
                        "port" : 443,
                        "cpe" : "cpe:/a:microsoft:internet_information_server:8.5",
                        "product" : "Microsoft IIS httpd"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "port" : 80,
                        "cpe" : "cpe:/o:microsoft:windows",
                        "product" : "Microsoft HTTPAPI httpd"
                    }
                ],
                "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-09-16T17:21:12.659Z")
            }
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "www2.shropscommunityhealth.nhs.uk",
            "firstSeen" : "2017-06-23 16:55:00",
            "a_rr" : "80.175.25.17",
            "data_retrieved" : ISODate("2019-09-16T17:21:12.663Z"),
            "asn" : 8607,
            "asn_org" : "Timico Limited",
            "city" : null,
            "country" : "United Kingdom",
            "shodan" : {
                "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-09-16T17:21:13.664Z")
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7fb679d76f3bbf82ed952e"),
    "org-name" : "Shropshire Community Health NHS Trust",
    "domain" : "shropscommunityhealth.nhs.uk",
    "subdomains" : [
        {
            "name" : "www.shropscommunityhealth.nhs.uk",
            "firstSeen" : "2015-10-17 01:10:00",
            "a_rr" : "195.49.146.9",
            "data_retrieved" : ISODate("2019-09-16T17:21:11.468Z"),
            "asn" : 21472,
            "asn_org" : "ServerHouse Ltd",
            "city" : "Portsmouth",
            "country" : "United Kingdom",
            "shodan" : {
                "ports" : [
                    {
                        "port" : 443,
                        "cpe" : "cpe:/a:microsoft:internet_information_server:8.5",
                        "product" : "Microsoft IIS httpd"
                    },
                    {
                        "port" : 80,
                        "cpe" : "cpe:/o:microsoft:windows",
                        "product" : "Microsoft HTTPAPI httpd"
                    }
                ],
                "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-09-16T17:21:12.659Z")
            }
        }
    ]
}
```